# STM32 clearing and setting up bits

Tags: arm, stm32

I'm new to STM32 and I could not figure out bitwise operation. For example I want to set adjust `CAN_MCR` register. I need to set bit 16 of this register and clear bit 15. I know I can do something like this:

```
CAN1-> MCR |=  CAN1_MCR_DBF;
CAN1->MCR ~= (CAN1_MCR_RESET);
```

I wonder if I can do something like this:

```
CAN1->MCR |= (0b10 << 15);
```

or

```
CAN1->MCR &= ~(0b10 << 15);
```

Since one is setting up the bit and other is clearing I do not know which operator should I use?

Another question is: If I want to check some specific bit of some register. How can I do that?
Let's say I want to check bit 15 of `CAN1_MCR` register. How can I do that? In PIC we could do that:

```
if(CAN1_MCR.B1==1){}
```

How can I do that in Arm? I know those are all simple questions but I could not find any useful answers for them.

Comment: in general you use or to set bits and and to clear bits.  So if you need to do both that is two operations.   This is C code so has nothing whatsoever to do with arm you just happen to be using something arm based with this C code.

Comment: likewise if you want to isolate a bit (or bits) from a register/variable you use AND.

Comment: However you could do that kind of tricks in PIC.

Comment: true there are other architectures as well.  there is a design feature in the cortex-m architecture that actually allows for you to isolate bits and not have to use two operations.  But did the chip vendor enable it and what is the address space used for that feature?  at least one stm32 chip doc only listed one address, and had to figure out the other from their library.

Comment: look for "bit banding" in cortex-m based products.

Comment: looks like it is limited to the m3/m4.  I dont see that you specified the chip you are using.  So in general it takes two operations, but you might have a shortcut depending on the product.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question you do could something like that: (*NOT TESTED: since I don't have definitions of macros or more details on what you need, I can only guess*)

```
CAN1->MCR = ( CAN1->MCR & (~(CAN1_MCR_DBF | CAN1_MCR_RESET)) ) |  CAN1_MCR_DBF;
```

It's not a very nice code, hard to read, but the benefit is that there is only one "read modify write" operation on the register.

Code readability put aside, keep in mind that in some cases it's better to modify two bits in two separate operations. In the present case I don't know, only the product datasheet can tell you if there are some constraints on bits set/clear (AFAIK there is no CAN_MCR register on STM32H7 at least).

About your second question I assume you are missing registers bitfields definitions on STM32, so I guess you are using STMicro HAL header files ?

There are several ways to handle registers but as far as I know the header files from STMicro do not use bitfields, so you will probably not be able to do something like `if(CAN1_MCR.B1==1){}`.

If you want to use bitfields you may want to redefine the STM32 registers.